# How can I determine the active column in a table during processing in order to modify it?

Tags: c++, qt, model, qt6

I don't quite understand how I can name my columns, and how I can change their type. For example, output in the first, a float in the second, and a QDataType in the third.

However, in the third one, I want to apply formatting. How do I tell the delegate that it is in the 3rd column, and it needs to apply date formatting?

The examples use `TableModelColumn`, but do not use the model class from QAbstractListModel:

```js
TableView {
    id: statisticsTable
    model: WD_RX
    interactive: false

    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: delegate
        implicitWidth: 70
        implicitHeight: 20
        Text {
            text: display
            anchors.fill: parent
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

```cpp
QVariant WeatherDataReceiver::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        if (index.column() == 0)
            return index.row();
        if (index.column() == 1)
            return QString::number(/*some float*/, 'f', 1);
        if (index.column() == 2)
            return QVariant(/*some QDataTime*/);
        
    }
    return QVariant(0);
}
```

I use `Context` to register the type.

main.cpp:

```cpp
WeatherDataReceiver wdr;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("WD_RX", &wdr);
```

I want to sign the columns and apply `Qt.formatTime(/*some date*/, "hh:mm")` to the third column.

My only solution was a condition on the type of the returned value, but I think this is not a very good solution, but also the naming of the column is left in question:

```js
TableView {
    id: statisticsTable
    model: WD_RX
    interactive: false

    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: delegate
        implicitWidth: 70
        implicitHeight: 20
        Text {
            text: {
                if (getType(display) !== 'object')
                    return display
                else
                    return Qt.formatTime(display, "hh:mm")
            }
            anchors.fill: parent
            horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
            verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The "column names" (*headers*) are part of the model, just like the rest of the data, you need to implement `headerData()` in a similar fashion. I suggest you to patiently study the [Model/View Programming guide](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html) which cover this and many other important aspects of Qt model/views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply different a front-end to each column, you have to use `DelegateChooser`. Then, you will be able to specify the index of the column you're working on.

And for giving them a title, here's an example of how you can implement the `headerData` function:

In your model.h

```
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override;
```

In your model.cpp

```
QVariant ModelTransactions::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal)
{
    switch (section)
    {
    case 0:
        return "Client";

    case 1:
        return "Document";

    case 2:
        return "Référence client";

    case 3:
        return "Type transaction";

    case 4:
        return "Opérateur";

    case 5:
        return "Montant";

    case 6:
        return "Référence bénéficiaire";

    case 7:
        return "Date";

    case 8:
        return "Token";

    case 9:
        return "Caissier";

    case 10:
        return "idTransaction";

    default:
        return QVariant ();

    }
}
else if (orientation == Qt::Vertical)
    return section + 1;

return QVariant ();

}
```

In the `if` part, you can give a name to each column. In the `else` you can give a number to each row, or a name if you find it usefull.

In your qml file, you should add a `HorizontalHederView` (also `VerticialHeaderView`) item to customize your titles:

```
HorizontalHeaderView
{
    id: hHeaderView
    syncView: tableView // give a id to your tableview and then paste it here
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height / 10


    delegate: Button
    { // replace cellWidth and cellHeight by  value of your choice
        implicitWidth: cellWidth
        implicitHeight: cellHeight
        width: cellWidth
        height: cellHeight



        background: Rectangle
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: Qt.rgba (0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.5)


        }

        contentItem: RowLayout
        {
            anchors.fill: parent
            Text
            {
                text: model.display
                color: "white"
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
             }
        }

       
    }

}
```